# Undefined reference to `xlCreateBookCA' C++

Tags: c++, eclipse

I'm trying to use the Libxl library in my eclipse c/c++ project.  Right now I'm using the minGW compiler in eclipse.

With this following code:

```
Book* book = xlCreateBook();
```

I get this error:

/src/xls2csv.cpp:22: undefined reference to `xlCreateBookCA'

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

You haven't got the library linked in. In Eclipse, right-click on your project and go to Properties. Next, open the Libraries section under GCC C++ Linker. In the Libraries (-l) panel add an entry with the value "xl" (I presume) and click OK. Make sure the directory in which this library is contained is in your LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable (you may need to restart Eclipse for this change to take effect).

Comment: Ok, I had already referenced the Cpp include files in the GNU C++ panel under preferences.  I also added the path to the Library paths in eclipse.  I'm using a windows system just to clarify because I forgot to mention it earlier.  It still does not seem to resolve the error.

Comment: Ohh my mistake!  You were on the right track all along.  Sorry about that.  I got some extra help and realized that what you were referring to was the MinGW linker.  I think it's working now.  Thank you for your help!